# jquery disable checkboxes when number of selected options reaches a certain point

Tags: jquery, events, click

I have several checkboxes in a form, I want to limit the users choices to 3 checkboxes, so when he selects 3, the rest of them become disabled (but if he deselects one, they all become enabled again).

Currently I have this code which pops up a message when a user tries to check a 4th box, however I just want all boxes to become disabled after three have been selected.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(event) {
if (this.checked && $('input:checked').length > 3) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('You\'re not allowed to choose more than 3 boxes');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(event) {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length >= 3) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
        alert("You're not allowed to choose more than 3 boxes");
    }
    else if {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').removeProp('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: For more consistent behavior, I would use `$('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled',false);` in place of `$('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').removeProp('disabled');`.

Comment: But the field will still be `disabled` with `prop('disabled', false)`

Comment: Try [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/FkYM5/). It's easy to confuse properties and attributes.